# Adding coffeescript to a given view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I have a coffescript file inside the javascript folder and being inside this folder, rails automatically adds it to all the views, but I want that file to be used only in a single view because if it is added to the other views you can alter them .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rails and Page Specific Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18724247/rails-and-page-specific-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

This is a relatively common problem, but there are a few things you can do to only render that javascript on a certain page.

## Javascript module pattern

Using the module pattern, you'll want to wrap most of your javascript in anonymous closures like so (in coffeescript):

```
do ->
  # ... all vars and functions are in this scope only
  # still maintains access to all globals
  return
```

The code inside the closures that you want to execute can be wrapped inside an object like this:

```
(($) ->
  myObj = myFunc: (param) ->
    # do stuff ...
    return

  $('selector').click ->
    myObj.myFunc()
    return
  return
) jQuery
```

So the code you want to execute is wrapped inside a function in an object, and then you can call that object when an event has fired. If the code you want to run in a single view is dependent only on user interactions like clicks, hovers, and other events, you can do something like this.

## Body css classes

In rails, you can add controller and action classes to your body tag. By doing this, you can use javascript to target the css class of the body and then either execute some code or not based on the class of the current view. It would look kind of like this:

In application.html.erb

```
<body class = "<%= controller_name %> <%= action_name %>"
```

Let's say that you want to execute some coffeescript for the `new` action of your `articles` controller, then in your coffeescript file:

```
if $('body').hasClass('articles') and $('body').hasClass('new')
  # do stuff for the articles#new
else
```

## Paloma gem

You could check out the [paloma gem](https://github.com/kbparagua/paloma), but I don't think the gem is actively maintained anymore.

I hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks, but it would be possible to do something like disable the require_tree and add tags with "src" that point to the address of the coffescripts and javascripts to add them manually in each file, in case there are some that need to be used throughout the project Are placed in the layaout and those that are not placed in their respective views. Would it be possible?

Comment: Yes it is technically possible to do that, but that goes heavily against the recommended and preferred rails way. It would also be a large performance issue since the server would have to serve a different asset on potentially every view. If you still want to do that, you would have to forgo the usage of the asset pipeline and manually configure each view to use a specific JavaScript file. I would persoanlly recommend option 2 above.